# Add to shape area image not saving as png

Tags: adobe-photoshop

This image is being saved but my original .psd file has (1,3) ,(1,4) and (1,4), (2,4) positioned 1s boxed. I created those boxes by using `rectangle tool` and then using `add to shape area`. The saved image is in .png format.

[image]

This is the image of my .psd file. [image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Thats a really old version of Photoshop. You may need to flatten the layers to save as PNG. Click Layer > Flatten Image, now try saving as PNG.  Alternatively don't use Photoshop for work like this.  Use a vector image editor instead. Inkscape is free. For Windows XP you'll need to download the older version - [Inkscape 0.92.3](https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-0.92.3/). You can export as PNG using Inkscape or save as SVG if you want the image for a web page.

Comment: See [Example screen shot](https://imgur.com/Pxr55s8), recreated in Inkscape in about 5 minutes.

Comment: I think you're expecting the paths on the *vector layer mask* to be visible. Mask paths never export as visible. They are *construction* paths, not object paths. You basically have a white shape, not 3 paths.

Comment: @Scott when I save the image, the boxes covering 1's disappear. I wanted to fix this problem

Comment: My point is you *don't* have shapes. You have a *vector mask*. Draw your shapes on a new layer. The layer structure you have is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Take the pencil tool and draw the areas. It's a single layer image and can well be saved as PNG, like this

[image]

Saving as PNG flattens all to a single layer. Vector shapes and texts are rasterized. That has happened automatically and without affecting the PSD under construction at least in Photoshop versions which are say 12 years old or younger. If your version refuses to do it, rasterize and merge the layers manually. Shapes (= layers with vector masks) and paths can have edge curves which are visible only when they are manipulated. Those curves are not a part of the image, they are shown to help the user in manipulations. They do not appear in PNG if they are not stroked.

**ADD after the questioner inserted** a screenshot of the problematic PSD:

Your Photoshop is about 20 years old and it draws automatically a stroke around the vector mask. As said, that stroke is a visualization tool, not a part of the image. It vanishes if you try to flatten the image or work with other layers and it does not appear in an exported PNG. If you draw a path it's visualized in the same way but it's not a part of the image  if it's not stroked.

If you want to work in Photoshop to make illustrations like this draw the curves as paths. Its selector is in the tool option line if you have the rounded rectangle tool or other vector drawing tool active. Paths do not generate new layers like vector mask shapes.

Here a bunch of rounded rectangles are drawn:

[image]

The drawn paths are shown in old Photoshop as thin curves. Those curve are not a part of the image, they are there to show what has been drawn. Real strokes must be inserted to make the curves permanently visible.

Prepare a new empty top layer. Select that layer.

Open the Paths panel. All drawn paths are cumulated as subpaths to Work Path. An unwanted subpath can be selected with the path selection tool (it's the arrow in the middle of the toolbar in my screenshot) and deleted.

Right click Work Path in Paths panel and select Stroke Path. The curves will be drawn to the currently selected  layer. The drawing happens with the last used drawing tool. Photoshop gives a possibility change the tool. The color = current foreground color.

[image]

If you already have otherwise good shapes drawn as vector masks like in your example you can insert to them a stroke as a layer style (=Layer > Layer Style > Stroke). You must turn layer Fill% to zero to keep the stroke but fade the fill color. Otherwise it covers curves below. Another possibility in BW version is to use layer blending mode Multiply.

Later ADD: I see there's suggested to use a vector drawing program for jobs like this. That's a perfectly good idea except it easily takes days to get properly started with one. Check if your system happens to contain Illustrator. It has somehow familiar look and feel for Photoshop users and that can help to get started.

Comment: how do I rasterized the vectors?

Comment: Texts and shape layers can be right clicked in the layers panel and rasterize is one of the available options. Strokeless paths must be either convert to selections (in the Paths panel) and the selection can be used to fill an area in an ordinary layer. The path can also be Stroked. The path appears as drawn with current brush onto currenly selected ordinary layer.

Comment: I've added an image of the .psd file. Please suggest me what I should do.

Comment: @ManjoyDas The case was tricky. But the answer is fixed.